# How to find elements within string in C++

Tags: c++, string, find

For a google URL, ex. https://www.google.com/search?q=some+query&oq=some+query&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2991j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

I need to grab the search engine (google.com)
Any queries (some, query)
and all options (oq, aqs, sourceid, and ie)

I'm assuming I need to find the characters in between the two backslashes for the search engine.
But how would I find every query when there can be and endless amount of them and I can't define a star and an end in the string to look for? The same goes with the options.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Be sure to add which language you want help with.  Tagging it in your question is even better!  And it helps to know what you've tried already.

Comment: I'd recommend using an existing library capable of parsing URLs rather than trying to do it from scratch and potentially having to deal with plenty of edge cases.

Comment: Look up the `std::string::find` method in your favorite C++ reference.  Also look for "std::string::substr` method.

Comment: Everything before the first unescaped `:` is the scheme, and after the `:` up to the first unescaped `?` is the host and path separated by unescaped `/`. Everything after the `?` up to an unescaped `#` is the query string, which *usually* contains `<name>=<value>` pairs separated by unescaped `&` characters. Everything after the `#` is a fragment. See [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) for the formal syntax. Splitting the URL you showed gives you these components: `https` `www.google.com` `/search` `q=some+query` `oq=some+query` `aqs=chrome..` `sourceid=chrome` `ie=UTF-8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use the example you gave: https://www.google.com/search?q=some+query&oq=some+query&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2991j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

The general idea here is to split the string based on certain delimiters. In this case, the various sections of the actual URL are divided based on "/". If we split the string based on that, we get this:

- https:
- www.google.com
- search?q=some+query&oq=some+query&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2991j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

The third section can be split further based on "&" to give:

- search?q=some+query
- oq=some+query
- aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2991j0j9
- sourceid=chrome
- ie=UTF-8

You can then split each of these based on "=" to get the option name and the value chosen. For example "sourceid=chrome" would split to give the option name "sourceid" and the value "chrome".

Implemented in actual C++ code it looks like this:

```
// Includes
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// For simplicity's sake, we'll call std::vector<std::string> "Tokens"
using Tokens = std::vector<std::string>;

// Create a function to return an std::vector<std::string>
Tokens getTokens(std::string inputString, std::string delimiter)
{
    // Create a list of tokens
    Tokens tokens;

    // Create a string to store the curernt token
    std::string token;

    // Iterate through until there are no more delimiters (at which our token will be identical to our input string)
    while (token != inputString)
    {
        // Set the token to the section of the input string from its beginning to where the first delimiter is found
        token = inputString.substr(0, inputString.find(delimiter));

        // If that token isn't empty append it to the list of tokens (we could get any empty token if two delimiters follow one another, e.g. //)
        if (token != "")
        {
            tokens.push_back(token);
        }

        // Remove the token from the original input string
        inputString = inputString.substr(inputString.find(delimiter) + 1);
    }

    return tokens;
}

int main()
{
    // This is our URL:
    std::string URL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=some+query&oq=some+query&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2991j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8";

    // Split up the URL into tokens based on the delimiter "/"
    Tokens URL_tokens = getTokens(URL, "/"); // <--- should contain three tokens, "https:", "www.google.com" and everything after that

    // Split up the third token of the URL tokens based on the delimiter "&"
    Tokens details_tokens = getTokens(URL_tokens[2], "&");

    // Print out the tokens
    std::cout << URL_tokens[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << URL_tokens[1] << "\n\n";

    for (int token = 0; token < details_tokens.size(); token++)
    {
        // Split into option and value
        Tokens option_and_value = getTokens(details_tokens[token], "=");

        std::cout << "Option: " << option_and_value[0] << "\n";
        std::cout << "Value: " << option_and_value[1] << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

On my computer this produced the following output:

```
https:
www.google.com

Option: search?q
Value: some+query

Option: oq
Value: some+query

Option: aqs
Value: chrome..69i57j0l5.2991j0j9

Option: sourceid
Value: chrome

Option: ie
Value: UTF-8
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the late response but this helped tremendously.

Comment: No worries :) You can simplify my code a lot further if you want but I made sure to write it in a way that's most readable rather than in the shortest way possible. Also if you think this is the correct answer to your question then I'd appreciate it if you accepted it.